# Loading old data in Notepad++(Notepad++ closed abnormally and all data is lost)

Tags: php, notepad++

I was coding in Notepad++. I was working on localhost and making changes regularly. The application(notepad++) closed abnormally and the code that I wrote during 3 days is lost. The .php file is empty now. There is nothing in it. 
Is there any way to get my code back. It was about 1000 lines and the algorithm was so important.

Comment: And what do you learn from this? Maybe save the file and don't code for 3 days without saving :)

Comment: I was saving it in per 1 minutes but the problem was like a bug of application. I saved and go to browser to control my code's output, when I click f5, I saw a blank page, notepad++ was crashed and when I try to open it again, I saw that my code was gone. After today, I am gonna put the backups in 234245 different location =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to get it back.

C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup

It keeps the backup of the files in above location.